# <logger> in log4net is not logging

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>  
      </layout>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="White" />
        <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Green" />
        <backColor value="White, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
    </appender>
    <appender name ="Rolling" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Users\AQureshi\Desktop\New folder\DailyLogsForProcessor.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Rolling" />
    </root>    
    <logger name="AnotherLog4NetTest.testing">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have the above log4net configuration in my appConfig file. The name attribute of the logger tag is the namespace and the class. So AnotherLog4NetTest is the namespace and it has a class called testing.
The idea is that only the class testing with write to console with the rest of he logs will be written to a file as specified in the `<root>` element.

But the logger is not logging on the console it is still logging to the file.
Can someone please tell me how to make my class testing log to console and the rest to a file.